# Losing DEM (from LAS Dataset) data coverage when calculated in higher resolution?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, lidar, lasd

I am trying to calculate DEMs for different resolutions (15 x 15, 7.5 x 7.5 and 3.75 x 3.75 m) using LAS Dataset To Raster tool in ArcGIS 10.5.

Unfortunately, no matter which settings I use for interpolation, the output DEMs do not cover the whole Las Dataset area (see image):

[image]

It seems that the calculated DEMs have shrunk proportionally the same in both (x and y) directions. The LAS Dataset extent is 27 x 9 km; however, if I use another LAS Dataset (with larger or smaller extent) I have the same issue.

I assume it is something in the cashing memory of the tool, or the environment settings, although I haven't changed anything there so they should be default.

Does anyone know what is going on there?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm) suggests that a study area boundary clip be included in the tool parameters to deal with the problem of interpolating along edges.  I suspect that the tool is automatically limiting the returned raster to areas that can be properly interpolated.

The problem with interpolation along the edge of a dataset, is that it only has points toward the center to use with the interpolation which can cause significant errors with the interpolation.  The solution to this is to include data outside the study area so that there are data points outside the edge to use in the interpolation.

Comment: I am aware of this problematic interpolations at the edges (have noticed it earlier). However, it is the Slope raster that I actually need to calculate from these DEMs. Therefore I wanted to apply the mask later on the Slope raster, not the DEM itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug and it seems that selecting a custom folder location causes it!
If I, however, save the output DEM in Default.gdb, then it seems to have the full spatial extent.